# You must select a parent organization or folder during project creation in google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google

We are trying to create project in google cloud platform but I am getting the below issue. Please can you check and provide solution for this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZohn.png)

Answer (score 0):

you have to read first: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization#acquiring

and check correct user/permissions

Comment: I have two account. Normal account i am not getting any errors. When i try in billing account i am getting an issue, what we have to give in location?

Comment: Your answer suggests a workable solution to the question is available via another website. The Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites [generally frowns on this type of answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) and consider revising your answer to include the steps required to resolve the issue.